# Autocomplete form using previous addresses using Angular

Tags: angular, autocomplete, observable

I am not very familiar with Angular but I have to work with it in this case. There is a service that returns a list of previously used addresses (strings) as `Observable<{name: string; value: string}>`. The call to this service is `this.jobAddressesService.getAddresses();` and it works just fine as intended. It's not something I have permission to modify, so I am leaving that alone.

Here is my HTML form. I am trying to filter the dropdown options as the user types.

```
          <mat-form-field class="w-100 mt-25" [class.input-disabled]="form.get('JobAddressID')?.disabled">
            <input type="text" matInput placeholder="*Select previously used address" formControlName="JobAddressID" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" class="w-100">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let elem of savedLocationsFiltered" [value]="elem.name">
                {{elem.name | truncateString: 60}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete> 
          </mat-form-field>
```

Here is my component, which I trimmed down to just the essentials for easier troubleshooting:

```
// A bunch of import statements here

@Component({
  selector: 'job-location-auth',
  templateUrl: './job-location-auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-location-auth.component.scss', '../../shared/css/tool-tip.scss']
})
export class JobLocationAuthComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  form: FormGroup;
  jobAddressID: FormControl;
  savedLocations: Observable<{ name: string; value: string }[]>;
  savedLocationsFiltered: any[] = [];

  private subs = new SubSink();

  constructor(
    private jobAddressesService: JobAddressesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initialize();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }

  initialize(): void {
    this.form = this.locationModel.formGroup;
    this.setJobAddressControl();
    this.formAddress = this.form.get('JobAddress') as FormGroup;
    this.getAddressList();
    this.filterAddresses();
  }

  setJobAddressControl(): void {
    // this method is fine
    this.jobAddressID = this.form.get('JobAddressID') as FormControl;
    this.subs.sink = this.jobAddressID.valueChanges.subscribe((value: number) => {
      if (value) {
        this.analyticsLoggingService.TrackEvent('JobDetails', 'JobAddress', 'Selected');
      }
      this.setAddress(+value);
    });
  }

  getAddressList(): void {
    this.savedLocations = this.jobAddressesService.getAddresses();
  }

  filterAddresses() {
    const jobAddress = this.form.get('JobAddressID');
    if (jobAddress) {
      jobAddress.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(200)
      .subscribe(
        res => this.getFilteredAddresses(res.value)
      );
    }
  }

  getFilteredAddresses(jobAddress: string): any {
    return this.jobAddressesService.getAddresses().pipe(
      filter(address => address.name.includes(jobAddress))
    ).subscribe(
      () => console.log('Job Address: ', jobAddress)
    );
  }

  saveAddress(): void {
    // functionality for setting address, works fine
  }
}
```

Specifically, it seems like my attempt to use filter() isn't working as intended, and I get "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined."

Comment: What's the question? :)

Comment: What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a list of previous addresses provided by an external service. I need to filter that list of addresses based on which addresses contain the string entered by the user. So a New York address will remain when a user types "New", but 1 Main Street, Atlanta address will disappear from that list that is displayed.

Of course, I will adjust for casing, but I can handle that part later.

Comment: try putting 
 this.getAddressList();
 this.filterAddresses();
in the constructor

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have both of those method calls in the initialize method.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Try changing your code to this:

```
  getFilteredAddresses(jobAddress: string): any {
    return this.jobAddressesService.getAddresses().pipe(
      filter(address => name.includes(jobAddress))
```

**Old Answer:**

The error you are getting is saying that address.name is `undefined`. You need to check why the response you are getting is returning an `undefined`. You can add the `tap` to print the object and take a look at what you are receiving from the service:

```
  getFilteredAddresses(jobAddress: string): any {
    return this.jobAddressesService.getAddresses().pipe(
      tap(address => console.log(address)),
      filter(address => address.name.includes(jobAddress))
```

It should print the response you are getting, where you can validate if you are receiving a proper response. If not, you should troubleshoot that with the back-end response.

Comment: I used tap and the results I am seeing in the console look fine to me. It's a long list of objects that look like this:

{name: "Alaska Township, MN, Test", value: 1}

I would assume that the "address" parameter would refer to each object in this list, so address.name shouldn't be undefined.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment and the updated edit. Your assumption is correct, assuming you are receiving an array of objects.